# Short format var declaration in for loop

Tags: go

Please see the code below. (A) is not ok in Go and I understand why. But why is (B) ok in Go ?

(A) is not ok: because re-definition of `a` (no new var in LHS of := )

(B) should be an error too: because re-definition of `r` (no new var in LHS of := ) as the loop will execute `r :=` with each iteration while `r` is still in scope.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]byte, 10)
    fmt.Println(a)
    a := make([]byte, 10) //not ok and I understand why : (A)
    fmt.Println(a)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        r := make([]byte, 10) //ok, but why is this ok? : (B)
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you may be mistaken about why (A) generates an error. The error you get for that second `a := ...` statement should be pretty explicit about the nature of the problem, and you can clearly see that (B) is not the same situation. It might help if you were to update your post to explain your understanding of why (A) is an error.

Comment: @larsks Updated my post with my understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The key idea behind the short format declaration is that it has to define at least one new variable in the current block. So it fails in the first case because it is attempting to redefine `a` in the current block without introducing any new variables. The second block works, because `r` is a new variable declared in the current block.

Comment: `The second block works, because r is a new variable declared in the current block.` But what about the second or third or nth iteration of the loop ? Won't r be re-defined with := ?. Updated the post with my current understanding.

Comment: It will be redefined in every iteration, correct. A block is a syntactic concept. It cannot be syntactically redefined in the same block, i.e. you cannot have another statement `r:=make(...)`

Comment: "It will be redefined in every iteration" --- will it actually be redeclared?

Answer (score 3):

As describe in go doc specifications about [Short_variable_declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), it is temporary for the scope.

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.
>
> Short variable declarations may appear only inside functions. In some contexts such as the initializers for "if", "for", or "switch" statements, they can be used to declare local temporary variables.

You can not redeclare same variable with short variable declaration in same scope.

```
a, a := 1, 2                              // illegal: double declaration of a or no new variable if a was declared elsewhere
```

In your case, `r` is in loop scope and each iteration `r` is a new variable. Because for loop repeats execution of a block.

> A ["for" statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) specifies repeated execution of a block

If you need to clarify this please run below loop code and see `r`'s memory addresses for each iterations. It will print five different addresses.

```
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        r := make([]byte, 10) //ok, but why is this ok? : (B)
        fmt.Printf("%p\n",r)
    }
```

Comment: My question was more along the lines of why is this allowed or even syntactically valid in Go ? Is this for loop usage of := allowed as a special case ? (while disallowed in function scope)

Comment: A ["for" statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) specifies repeated execution of a block`.